# Hardware watchdog for my ESP32 Board - circuit and design suggestion

Tags: power, design, watchdog

i've made my custom board based on LM2596, LM1117, ESP32 with ethernet based on LAN8720. This works without any issue but i want to prevent any type of software issues/hangs using an external watchdog timer.

The total board consumes (more or less) 1A.

I've seen a lot of circuits based on TPL5010 LM555...but i'm a little bit confused on which direction i can take.

Basically, i need two main functionalities:

1. The "heartbeat" will be sent from ESP32 to the watchdog using a GPIO
2. If (for example) no "heartbeat" will be received for 90 seconds (more or less) i need the reset from the watchdog, but i want a sort of "Hard reset" leaving the power line (managed from the watchdog via mosfet) disconnected for 10 seconds and then back again with the power supply.

[This is my initial idea](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0lwzGATAVhAFhdA7Gd7d4kA2ADgE5JyRskQ0VJ6BTAWjDACgxi0lJS4fCCJM86DBmjkZs8ik4BzcNmIjSEsKoxwoUTgCcVarSe0c6YuNcicA7sfDIQSWk8ucASuCSCLGP2cmJnQmNGCoaAUHZEC6U3d9ZXhICRS01JF+PVsHV3jneHgTIPsRYsSiszVbIwT67Xy9AhtOAGMXN3TOungNPTA2QXhoIrHxifhw2EguZSa+iSbQiNyXARdQ9cEmtf4dtwTd9pBWfZdSQXZhX0ExGZtHm0HWbCk5D7lSabg58DVujwdKsyitEuhSGJSnkNg1qvoeHQIVCkZDwOQ6HQACbMABmAEMAK4AGwALqxicwseAcpFZpxQvBThD0XQ0agauB4AB9YjobmQbmhGTclACh5UVQoYiobnsblIblgHnwTj8ahHQ7aRY5CWffWycDQb7YfC8YgW9BkGRMmC-cCGU7nW5OjbFO7gVrKM5usiuwRg4KcanXNIoOihi47cAAOXQeFISlO4hE4eTwkD+gcrCIUdOfLza1YBZdrHIahdtgAMk7pT1axWNmIQATiQBnZj0LMN+tnOuVsp9iuXf2Fzi4jC587I7ZZI0-JBJmdIJASGeZ2rlRsBqdNjDYMpVcG6fybsvDq7l1OWTrWJPn6+nK8bwcp0tXgcTnOYkdAl25sAojpRcYgrLUwI8AB7cBBALEIwEgTEgLtaxyClGVwhcGCRE4IA), maybe it's a little bit overcomplicated but it does (only on simulator) what i need to do.

[image]

I have only a question, instead connecting a led (that is used for this example) i want to connect the 5V that feeds the LM1117 in order to switch off and then switch on the LM1117 regulator: how i can do that?

It exist something more simple and less complicated?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a pity the LM1117 doesn't have an EN pin. Could you modify the design to use a regulator that does?

Comment: Yes: in this case which part you suggest?

Comment: if you go to the product page for the LM1117, they suggest the TLV767 as an alternative which does have an EN pin. But there will be many more that you can find with their parametric search tool.

Comment: Make sure to check whether EN is active high or low, and adapt accordingly.

Comment: Instead changing the LM1117 i can use this modified circuit (uses N Channel mosfet) in order to feed the +5V of the LM1117 that comes from out pin of NE555? You think that can works without any issue? https://tinyurl.com/2dl8x4ks

The mosfet is: AO3400A